# show the dropdown in parent component and data should be in another component in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular9, angular12

I want to show dropdown  in parent component and  data is in child component and i need show the data when I select dropdown in parent component and i want to show the the data in child component based on selection using ngmodel.

Comment: I have edited the answer and added the example link below, do check out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @output decorator and event emitter for sending the data from child to parent and to send the data from parent to child back you can use @Input decorator

Find my updated stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-15r9lw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts)

For more clarity please refer to below Angular IO official document : https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs